# Java - Pattern matches but fails to capture

Tags: java, regex

Here are three sample lines from my dataset:

```
|   |   |   |   featureB >= 16104.33 : 18873.52 (1/0)

|   featureA >= 17980.32

featureC = ABC BLAH BLAH blA'H $blah 4/ blah blah
```

I am trying to come up with a pattern matcher which would capture the following:

- feature name
- the relation (=, >=, <)
- feature value (could be a mix of numbers and/or characters, but never contains a colon)
- result ( the value that comes after the colon and before the bracket - the colon and the result are optional and may not appear on some lines)

I came up with the following pattern, but it fails to capture the feature value:

```
Pattern.compile("(?:\\|   )*(.*?)(>?=|<)((?!:).)*(?::?)(.*?)(?:\\(.*\\))?")
```

So basically my aim is for `group(1)` to contain the feature name, `group(2)` to contain the relation, `group(3)` to contain the feature value, and `group(4)` to contain the result if it exists.

Currently `group(1)`, `group(2),` and `group(4)` produce what I'm expecting but `group(3)` is never captured and is always empty.

I would appreciate any help/advice.

Comment: Are you sure `group(4)` is what you expect?

Comment: @MarounMaroun positive; I just checked a few hundred records and they all seem to have appropriate values for `group(4)`

Comment: https://regex101.com/ fails with your regex and example.

Comment: `((?!:).)*` is matches what you expect it to, but it only *captures* one character at a time.  What you're seeing is the last character, which happens to be a space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your well drafted requirements I came up with this regex to capture all 4 groups (4th being the optional one):

```
^[ |]*(\w+)\s*(>?=|<)\s*([^:]+)(?:\s*:\s*([^()]*))?
```

Java pattern:

```
Pattern p = Patttern.compile("^[ |]*(\\w+)\\s*(>?=|<)\\s*([^:]+)(?:\\s*:\\s*([^(]+))?.*$");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tR2dH8/4)

Comment: I think the parenthesized bit at the end of the first line is not supposed to be captured: *"...after the colon and before the bracket..."*

Comment: Very close, though it doesn't match the values that come after the result (they need to be matched but not captured). Thank you for the answer.

Comment: If those extra values don't need to be captured then we don't even need to match it to expedite the regex execution for large text.

Comment: If you use the `matches()` method, the whole string has to be accounted for.  That's probably what he means.  Just tack a `.*` onto the end.  And that would mean you don't need the `(?m)^` either.

Comment: Yes `.*` has been added to support `matches()` (otherwise previous one was suitable for `find()`) What I meant is that by ignoring rest or using `.*` this regex completes in 76 steps on regex101 however the one OP accepted takes 430 steps (6x more).

Comment: Actually, the poor performance of @Thorben's regex is caused by the reluctant quantifier in `([^:]+?)`, which is only needed to prevent the regex from matching across line boundaries.  Change it to `([^:\n]+)` and it's just as fast as yours ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/bP6xJ4/2)).  But the OP is matching each line as a standalone string, so even that isn't necessary.

Answer (score 2):

In group 5 is the optional bracket content.

```
^[ |]*(\w+)\s*(>?=|<)\s*([^:]+?)(?:\s*:\s*([^\(]+))?(\(.*)?$
```

See example @  https://regex101.com/r/bP6xJ4/1

Answer (score 1):

This appears to work for all of your inputs:

```
(\s*\|\s*)*(\w+)\s*(<=?|>=?|=)([^:]+)(:(.*)$)?
|--------| |---|   |---------||-----||-|--|-|
     1       2          3        4    5 6
```

Or, in Java

```
Pattern.compile("(\\s*\\|\\s*)*(\\w+)\\s*(<=?|>=?|=)([^:]+)(:(.*)$)?");
```

`group(2)` is the feature name, `group(3)` is the operator, `group(4)` is the value, and `group(6)` is the result.

This is an excellent resource for testing regular expressions:

http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html